# TYPO3 - Get the current language in an external php file

Tags: typo3

I am a beginner in TYPO3 :) and I want to get the current language in an external php file.

How can I do that?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What do you mean by external php file?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you've got an instance of the TSFE, you can access the `sys_language_uid` via `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid`

Comment: I don't have to include any file to use it ?

I get an error : Notice: Undefined index: TSFE in.........

Comment: Well, if file is included in your TYPO3 as USER or USER_INT, not. How do you include your file? or does it run outside the TYPO3 context?

Comment: Thanks, it run outside the TYPO3 context

Comment: Since TYPO3 9, use Language Aspect: https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/master/en-us/ApiOverview/Context/Index.html

Answer (score 16):

For the V9, `$GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid` is deprecated, it recommanded to use the Language Aspect.

Example :

```
$languageAspect = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Context\Context::class)->getAspect('language');
$sys_language_uid = $languageAspect->getId();
```

Answer (score 8):

TYPO3 9+

```php
$context = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Context\Context::class);

// The requested language of the current page as integer (uid)
$currentLanguageUid = $context->getPropertyFromAspect('language', 'id');
```

Answer (score 7):

It is always best way to get Current language:

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_uid
```

or

```
$GLOBALS['TSFE']->sys_language_content
```

based on that you get current language id and you can give condition for that.

Get Current Language in Typo3 10.x version or later.

```
$context = GeneralUtility::makeInstance(\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Context\Context::class);
$langId = $context->getPropertyFromAspect('language', 'id');
```

Answer (score 1):

> In case you need detailed language attributes

```
$request = $GLOBALS['TYPO3_REQUEST'];
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\DebuggerUtility::var_dump(
    $request->getAttribute('language')
);
```

Further get attributes like i.e. Path of language

```
$path = $request->getAttribute('language')->getBase()->getPath();
```

Reference : https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ApiOverview/SiteHandling/AccessingSiteConfiguration.html

Answer (score 0):

Normally L is always be used as a language parameter in typo3. $_GET['L']

Comment: `$_GET[L]` can be unset or empty